# Run ImageMagick as a python subprocess on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imagemagick-convert, aws-lambda

I'm looking to generate an animated GIF by giving AWS lambda a series of images from my s3 bucket, which it downloads into its /tmp/ folder.

I read in the docs that imagemagick comes preinstalled on lambda, but for some reason I can't call it through a python subprocess:

```
import subprocess

# ... some code later ...

# Now, generate the gif  
input_dir = '/tmp/'
output_dir = '/tmp/'

args = (['convert', '-delay', '60', '-dispose', 'Background', '+page'] +
        files_list +
        ['-loop', '0', os.path.join(output_dir, 'animation.gif')])

try:
    subprocess.check_call(args)
    print("gif was generated")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("gif produced errors ...")
    print(e.output)
```

any idea how I can go about calling imagemagick through a subprocess on lambda?  I've been able to get this working locally and on ec2, but no luck on lambda.  The only response I get is it generates a blank .gif file and returns an empty exception thread after outputting "gif produced errors ...".

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagemagick is preinstalled only if your lambda function is written in **Node.js**. But your lambda function written in Python.

From [Lambda support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)

> AWS Lambda supports the following runtime versions:

- Node.js: v0.10.36
- Java: Java 8
- Python: Python 2.7

> If you author your
> Lambda function code in Node.js, the following libraries are available
> in the AWS Lambda execution environment so you don't need to include
> them:
>
> ImageMagick: Installed with default settings. For versioning
> information, see imagemagick nodejs wrapper  and  ImageMagick native
> binary  (search for "ImageMagick"). AWS SDK: AWS SDK for JavaScript
> version 2.2.12
>
> If you author your Lambda function code in Python, the
> following libraries are available in the AWS Lambda execution
> environment so you don't need to include them:
>
> AWS SDK for Python (Boto 3) version 1.2.1
>
> There are no additional
> libraries available for Java.

Comment: dang ... do you know if there is anything else I can do?  Is it possible to package imagemagick as well? Looks like I'll have to move the entire script out of lambda onto a server after all ...

Comment: Never used that before. You can try PythonMagick which is a Python interface to ImageMagick. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick

Comment: "You can try PythonMagick which is a Python interface to ImageMagick."

Yes, but, PythonMagick is not preinstalled on AWS Lambda, so you would have to include it in your deployment package, which is not easy. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html?shortFooter=true#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python for instructions.